# Why the destructor of TTreeNode is called BEFORE parent TTreeview destructor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Deeply apologize, I try hard, but I can not find any plausible explanation.

There is my own `TMyTreeNode` class:

```pascal
TMyTreeNode = class (TTreeNode)
private
  FFont:TFont;
  FBrush:TBrush;
public
  constructor Create; 
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property Font:TFont read FFont write FFont;
  property Brush:TBrush read FBrush write FBrush;
end;

constructor THierarchyTreeNode.Create(AOwner: TTreeNodes);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FFont := TFont.Create;
  FBrush := TBrush.Create;
end;

destructor TMyTreeNode.Destroy;
begin
  FFont.Free;
  FBrush.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

and a descendant of `TTreeView`, in which `TMyTreeNode` is dynamically created.

I override dynamic method `procedure TMyTreeview.Delete(Node: TTreeNode);` in order to implement specific behavior, when `TMyTreeNode` is to be removed. I need to iterate through all other `TMyTreeNode` objects to change their properties. Just for simplicity, I force them to show their text:

```pascal
TMyTreeview = class(TTreeView)
protected
  function CreateNode: TTreeNode; override;
  procedure Delete(Node: TTreeNode); override;
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
        
function TTreeViewHierarchy.CreateNode: TTreeNode;
// var LClass: TTreeNodeClass;
begin
// LClass := THierarchyTreeNode;
// if Assigned(OnCreateNodeClass) then
//   OnCreateNodeClass(Self, LClass);
// Result := LClass.Create(Items);
// The constructor of THierarchyTreeNode is not called, because constructor of TTreeNode is not virtual !!!;
  Result := THierarchyTreeNode.Create(Items);
end; 

procedure TMyTreeview.Delete(Node: TTreeNode);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  for i := 0 to Items.Count-1 do ShowMessage(Items[i].Text); //Example  
end;

destructor TMyTreeview.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

Suppose 5 `TMyTreeNode` objects are added into `TMyTreeview`. When the selected node is deleted by `myTreeview.Items.Delete(myTreeview.Selected);` the destructor of `TMyTreeNode` is called at first, and then the method `TMyTreeview.Delete()`.

`ShowMessage()` shows itself 5 times. This shows, that the node, which is going to be deleted and all other `TMyTreeNode` objects exist and are properly referenced.

It is expected behavior.

But when I close the application, I get an error message:

> ...class ETreeViewError with message 'Invalid index'

in the `TMyTreeview.Delete()` method.

There are 2 things which are very confusing for me:

1. In case of closing (destroying) the `MainForm` of the application, `TMyTreeNode.Destroy()` is called BEFORE `TMyTreeview.Destroy()`, why? The owner of the `TTreeNodes` is `TCustomTreeView`, and I would expect that `TTreeNodes` would be freed in the ancestor's destructor (`TTreeView.Destroy()`).
2. If I admit that strange fact above, then `procedure TMyTreeview.Delete(Node: TTreeNode);` fails. It seems that the `Items` are already dereferenced and `Items.Count` does not provide the correct outcome (it comprises of dereferenced pointers). But it makes no sense.

Thanks in advance. I spent hours to debug this, but despite my long term experience in Delphi, I can not get it.

Comment: does it make a difference if you put inherited after your showmessage loop?

Comment: @whosrdaddy no... I tried... btw seems logical, I admit

Comment: Aren't you meant to override the virtual constructor of TTreeNode, and get the tree view class to instantiate your derived class. There is a mechanism for that which I don't recall off the top of my head. If you want to know why the destructor runs in that order, look at the code using the debugger and the call stack. It will be easy to understand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can not force debugger to jump inside ComCtrls.pas, it always skip.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan . David, I also rewrote constructor of TMyTreeNode (see above), but what is strange, I can not set breakpoints there. Font and Brush is nil.... Why? I could not find anything on web, it seems you could be right, but anyway it is confusing

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the constructor of TTreeNode is not virtual, so my construcor was not called in function TMyTreeview.CreateNode: TTreeNode. Anyway there is still problem with destructors.

Comment: Can you override CreateNode? You can debug in ComCtrls if you enable debug dcus.

Comment: I set up debugger so I can go inside, but what cause TTreeNode to be destroyed is mystery... I can override CreateNode, it is virtual, but I must call TMyTreeNode's constructor explicitely, otherwise it will not be created properly.

Comment: "but I must call TMyTreeNode's constructor explicitely, otherwise it will not be created properly" that is exactly what is expected.

Comment: @lyborko The *correct* way to use a custom `TTreeNode`-derived class in `TTreeView` is to either 1) override the TreeView's `CreateNode()` method to call `TMyTreeNode.Create()` directly, or 2) handle the TreeView's `OnCreateNodeClass` event to return `NodeClass=TMyTreeNode`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: 2) that's catch...  OnCreateNodeClass is not usable, because the constructor of TTreeNode is not virtual.

Comment: @remy that thought was behind my first comment but I guess things changed since D7 regarding the node class constructor being virtual

Comment: @lyborko "*the constructor of TTreeNode is not virtual*" - it has been virtual since Delphi 2009: `TTreeNode = class(TPersistent) ... public constructor Create(AOwner: TTreeNodes); virtual; ... end;` The `OnCreateNodeClass` event was introduced in Delphi 6, but the `TTreeNode` constructor wasn't made virtual until Delphi 2009. I didn't notice your question was about Delphi 7. In which case, overriding `CreateNode()` is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

When the component TTreeview is to be destroyed, it gets WM_DESTROY message in `procedure TCustomTreeView.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);`.

Subsequently the `procedure TCustomTreeView.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotify);`  is called, where `TWMNotify.NMHdr^.Code = TVN_DELETEITEM`.

```
TVN_DELETEITEM:
        begin
          Node := GetNodeFromItem(PNMTreeView(NMHdr)^.itemOld);
          if Node <> nil then
          begin
            Node.FItemId := nil;
            FChangeTimer.Enabled := False;
            if FStateChanging then
              Node.Delete
            else
              Items.Delete(Node);
          end;
        end;
```

It simply deletes `TTreeNodes` before `TTreeview.destructor` is called. In this case
`ComponentState` is set to `csDestroying`, so the one way from the trap may be:

```
procedure TMyTreeview.Delete(Node: TTreeNode);
var i:Integer;
begin
   inherited;
   if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) 
        then for i := 0 to Items.Count-1 do ShowMessage(Items[i].Text);
end;
```

Btw. Thanks, David...